# Don't understand why I am not getting my Image?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I am working on an demo application where I am taking picture then save it.
I want to display picture inside Image view . I don't understand why it is not working . I recently tried out some solution but non of them worked for me .
Is there anyone who can tell me what's wrong with my code .

// This is my code

```
    private Button takePictureButton;
        private ImageView imageView;
        private Uri file;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            takePictureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_image);
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                takePictureButton.setEnabled(false);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
            if (requestCode == 0) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED&&grantResults[2]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    takePictureButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        }

        public void takePicture(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            file = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);

            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        }

        private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraDemo");

            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                    Log.d("CameraDemo", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                if (requestCode == 100) {
//Code that bind image with ImageView

                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        imageView.setMaxHeight(100);
                        imageView.setMaxWidth(100);
                        imageView.setImageURI(null);
                        imageView.setImageURI(file);
                    }
                }
```

//Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the issue you are facing crash?

Comment: What's wrong with this question ?why downvote?

Comment: I am not getting image where I want to display that .

Comment: I don't know about down votes. I understand that your image is not displaying. I am asking is there any null pointer or any other issue?

Comment: No there is no issue no error just                    i  unable to set image see the code at the bottom  where i bind the file with imageView

Comment: @Champandorid What is your android version?

Comment: Marshmallow Don't tell me to ask run time permission, That code work fine I gave all the permission at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what are you doing at here. But :

```
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                        Uri uri = data.getData();
                        imageView.setMaxHeight(100);
                        imageView.setMaxWidth(100);
                        imageView.setImageURI(uri);
    }
```

Replace this code on your activityResult, it is working for me.

Comment: Is activityResult called?  Is your if stat was called? Are you sure imageview is visible? Did you tried with any placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will work

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
     if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
        onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
     else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
        onCaptureImageResult(data);
  }
}
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
  Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

  File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

  FileOutputStream fo;
  try {
     destination.createNewFile();
     fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
     fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
     fo.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }

  ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}
```

For more See this http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-sample

Answer (score 0):

In My case it worked for me:

```
private static Bitmap Image = null;
private static Bitmap rotateImage = null;   



@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.e("resultCode", Integer.toString(resultCode));
        Log.e("requestCode", Integer.toString(requestCode));
            Log.e("Inside If","Success");
            Uri mImageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                Image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mImageUri);
                if (getOrientation(getApplicationContext(), mImageUri) != 0) {
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(getOrientation(getApplicationContext(), mImageUri));
                    if (rotateImage != null)
                        rotateImage.recycle();
                    rotateImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(Image, 0, 0, Image.getWidth(), Image.getHeight(), matrix,true);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(rotateImage);
                    //saveImagetoFolder(rotateImage);
                } else {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(Image);
                   // saveImagetoFolder(Image);

                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```